# Magento 2: how to get CMS Pages using REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

i want to get all cms pages using REST api i am trying to get via http://localhost/rest/V1/cmsPage/searchs but getting error

```
The "searchs" value's type is invalid. The "int" type was expected. Verify and try again.
```

what is proper way to get all cms pages data via REST api without any fillter parametter ?
any help appreciate..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use "**search**" instead of "**searchs**". It's typo and also you need to specify search criteria fields. Execute this below URL in your postman

```
{baseurl}/rest/V1/cmsPage/search?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=identifier&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=asc
```